# How can I remove the second occurrence of the decimal number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I remove the `second` occurrence of the decimal number $275.75 in the received subTotal using regex and include `$`in the regex ? But now I am getting NaN as output.

Expected output:

Here is the result: $275.75

```
let subTotal = "\n \n Sub-Total \n \r \r $275.75 \n\n $275.75";
let myTotal = Number(subTotal.replace(/\n|\r|[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));

console.log("Here is the result: "+myTotal);
```

Comment: You want a second occurrence but both are the same btw.

Comment: You could see the  `subTotal` is  having the text ` \n \n Sub-Total \n \r \r $275.75 \n\n $275.75` Using regex, how can I console log $275.75 ? My existing regex output gives 275.75275.75 which is not a number ,so results in NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\b\d+\.\d+\b
```

[image]

and get all numbers with a decimal point in an array and get the specific element using array index

```js
let subTotal = "\n \n Sub-Total \n \r \r $275.75 \n\n $275.75";
let myTotal = subTotal.match(/\b\d+\.\d+\b/g);
console.log(myTotal);
console.log(`Here is the result: $${myTotal[0]}`);
```

or

```
\$\b\d+\.\d+\b/g
```

[image]

```js
let subTotal = "\n \n Sub-Total \n \r \r $275.75 \n\n $275.75";
let myTotal = subTotal.match(/\$\b\d+\.\d+\b/g);
console.log(myTotal);
console.log("Here is the result: " + myTotal[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, may I know what is happening when we apply `\b ` in regex pattern ?

Comment: @soccerway `\b` is word boundary and I've updated the answer with an image. That'll help you to understand better

Comment: Awesome , this helps me better .

Comment: (In this part `\$\b\d+` the word boundary is implicit as the word boundary would always match there, so you could omit it)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a replace (since you're not using the string in your output) [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) might be a better alternative. Just grab the first `match` with `/\$[0-9\.]+/`.

```js
let subTotal = "\n \n Sub-Total \n \r \r $275.75 \n\n $275.75";

let myTotal = subTotal.match(/\$[0-9\.]+/);

console.log(`Here is the result: ${myTotal}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t use regex, but it still returns what you want. This is the example code from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) site. It uses `Number.prototype.toFixed`

```js
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(financial(123.456));
// expected output: "123.46"

console.log(financial(0.004));
// expected output: "0.00"

console.log(financial('1.23e+5'));
// expected output: "123000.00"
```

What you may want

```js
let myTotal = financial(subTotal.match(/[\d+\.]/)[0])
console.log("Here is the result: $"+myTotal);
```